# How to upload image file that converted thumbnails with javascript & PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I have some code in which, before uploading the original images, it creates thumbnail images.
What I want to do is, instead of uploading the client's original images, I'd like to upload the thumbnail images. The reason is that the originals image files are usually too big, and my system's OK with very small images such as thumbnails. How can I achieve my goal?

Here is my code so far:

#### PHP code:

```
if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['action'])) {
   $SafeFile = $_FILES['client_image']['name'];
}
```

#### HTML code:

```
< input type="file"  valign=middle  name="client_image" id="client_image" >
< output id="list" > <  /output>
```

#### JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('client_image').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" id="thumb_image" src="', e.target.result,
                                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };  
        })(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're targetting modern browsers with `<canvas>` support, there is nothing you can do in JS to shrink a gif/jpg on the client. There is simply no practical way to do pixel-level operations on images in any practical manner.

Comment: You can, however do it in Flash/Java but of course your code isn't guaranteed to run so you'll need to handle failure gracefully

Comment: All my clients're supposed to use Chrome, but before looking for the solution with HTML 5. with the above code, I was able to create small size thumnail image. All I want to do is uploading this image. Is there a way to upload this thumnail image?

Answer (score 0):

Only solution that works on all popular browsers is to use flash uploader with image pre-processing.

[SWFUploader](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) (version >=2.5.0) have this feature.

Here is a example of usage (folder `demos/resizedemo`): [SWFUpload_v250_beta_3_samples.zip](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/downloads/detail?name=SWFUpload_v250_beta_3_samples.zip)